# How to generate a list from a column in PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I create a query to ganerate a dates as rows,

```
SELECT ltrim(TO_CHAR(MONTH,'mm-yyyy'),'0') AS process_date
FROM 
(
    select add_months (trunc (to_date('09/01/2019','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'MM'), 1*Level -1)
           Month
    FROM Dual
        CONNECT BY Level <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date('09/01/2019','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('09/01/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')) + 1
    order by month
)
```

The result is

```
PROCESS_DATE|
------------|
1-2019      |
2-2019      |
3-2019      |
4-2019      |
5-2019      |
6-2019      |
7-2019      |
8-2019      |
9-2019      |
10-2019     |
11-2019     |
12-2019     |
1-2020      |
```

I need your help to create a plsql function to convert those rows to a list, like

```
[1-2019,2-2019,3-2019,...]
```

Comment: Do you want a string with all the values concatenated ? Or do you want a data structure that has all the values as elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   LISTAGG(process_date, ',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY process_date)
  FROM   (SELECT   LTRIM (TO_CHAR (month, 'mm-yyyy'), '0') AS process_date
            FROM   (    SELECT   ADD_MONTHS (
                                     TRUNC (TO_DATE ('09/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
                                            'MM'),
                                     1 * LEVEL - 1)
                                     month
                          FROM   DUAL
                    CONNECT BY   LEVEL <=
                                     MONTHS_BETWEEN (
                                         TO_DATE ('09/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
                                         TO_DATE ('09/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
                                     + 1
                      ORDER BY   month))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function on ORACLE.

Use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on MSSQL.

Comment: Regardless of whether the OP accepts it an answer which consists solely of links to external sites is not regarded as a good answer. Good answers should be complete in their own right, with links to documentation as a support if necessary.

Comment: Also, questions tagged `[sql]` just indicate that the question is about writing database programs using SQL language. It does not (or should not) refer to MSSQL, for which we have the `[sql-server]` tag (and variants). So only an Oracle solution is required here.